# cannot find where to install PILLOW

Tags: installation, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

Trying to install python PILLOW for python 3.7 on a windows laptop for a project, and have no idea where to do this. I've tried installing through the command prompt, but it does not accept "pip install Pillow".

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#windows-installation